# thickbox plugin - Identify

Tags: javascript, jquery, thickbox

I'm calling the (fairly old) plugin "thickbox" as described here:

```
<input type="text" id="RecordType" size="10">
<a id="RecSubTypeHref" href="index.pl?img=true&type=RecSubType" class="thickbox" disabled title='Title goes here'><img border=0 src='images/questionmark.png'></a>
```

When the thickbox is created it contains a list of stuff based on the query.

Using JavaScript or jQuery I'd like to be able to access the value of `type` (in the example above `type=RecSubType`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Adapted from http://tinyurl.com/pqxtu2
function getQuerystring(url, key, default_)
{
  if (default_==null) default_="";
  key = key.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]"+key+"=([^&#]*)");
  var qs = regex.exec(url);
  if(qs == null)
    return default_;
  else
    return qs[1];
}

var href = $('a#RecSubTypeHref')[0].href;
console.log(getQuerystring(href, 'type'));
```

### [Live demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/M7Meq/)

Too easy ;)

---

<sup>(Also see [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript) for more handy query string parsing approaches.)</sup>